# Databricks - Writing CSV as a Parquet folder even when specified as a CSV file

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have some code performing some ETL which is working perfectly fine with Databricks. However I have a colleague who wants the data in a CSV format so they can ingest the information into their local SQL database.

Currently I write all the data out in Parquet like this

```
filelocation = f"/mnt/successfactors-work/{dimname}/{year}/{year}{month}/{dimname}_{year}{month}{day}.parquet"
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(filelocation)
```

This all works perfectly fine, immediately beneath this I then have code written like:

```
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(f"/mnt/successfactors-work/{dimname}/{dimname}.csv")
```

However what appears to happen is rather than write to a single CSV file, it writes to multiple files within the folder, I assume this is because of the distributed processing nature of Databricks/Spark? Is this the case? Is there a way of having it just write as a singular CSV?

Its possible to get a single CSV however I have to run the data within databricks and then use the UI to do a df.display() and download using the icon - this is not ideal.

Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using Pyspark `DataFrame.write()` **always creates a folder** and within are the required files. Your data (when large) is often repartitioned and written as multiple files inside this folder and these are called `part files`.
- So, to write data as a single file inside this folder, you can use `DataFrame.repartition()` or `DataFrame.coalesce()`. These methods help writing the dataframe to **N** number of part files, where **N** is passed as an argument to the above methods.
- Therefore you can change the code to the following:

```
df.repartition(1).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(f"/mnt/successfactors-work/{dimname}/{dimname}.csv")
```

**Note:** If you don't want to write the file into folder, you have to use pandas dataframe to write instead of pyspark. You can try using to following code for this:

```
pandas_df = df.toPandas()

pandas_df.to_csv(f"/dbfs/mnt/successfactors-work/{dimname}/{dimname}.csv", mode='w', index=False)
```